# Logstash field name start with

Tags: json, field, logstash

For example i have the following JSON:

```
{
  params{
    firstname : value1,
    .lastname : value2
  }
}
```

How can i check if the name of a field (not the value) start with `"."` and delete it?

B.R

Comment: Could you give us valid json please? With double quotes? And the rights colon?

Comment: Also your full configuration would be useful in order to answer without asserting a lot of things about it.

Comment: For confidential reason i can't give you more details but imagine i receive this message request:
`timestamp=11111$firstname=value1$.lastname=value2`

im searching a filter that can transform `.lastname` to `lastname`
Hope you understand me.

Comment: The de_dot filter would do, as its role is to remove all dots from field names (cf my answer)

Answer (score 0):

If your are using the json filter to parse the json you can use the mutate filter with gsub to remove all the `"."` before using the json filter. But only if you are sure the dots are only in the beginning of the field names.

It would look like this :

```
# Removing all the dots from the field message
mutate {
    gsub => ["message", "\.", ""]
}

json {
    source => "message"
}
```

---

There is an alternative, which is the de_dot filter. You'll have to install it and it is apparently expensive ressource-wise.

[de_dot filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-de_dot.html)